# Initialising a ViewController before Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

I am performing a segue to a view controller that requires an initialisation process.  At present the initialisation happens in ViewDidLoad of the target view controller.  However the initialisation is fairly lengthy and I would like to show a spinner while it is happening.

If I create a UIActivityIndicatorView within ViewDidLoad and run the initialisation on another thread, of course ViewDidLoad exits and the rest of the loading process happens - in particular shouldAutorotate is called, and this contains code that assumes the initialisation process has occurred.  (Even if it didn't, I do not want to show the target view before it has been initialised.)

The answer seems to be to initialise the target view controller before calling the segue.  However I can't do that in prepareForSegue in the calling view controller, for the same reason - it exits and the segue is called before the initialisation has happened.

So I seem to need to instantiate the target controller, initialise it and then perform the segue with the initialised controller as the destination.  My problem is that I don't know how to do that.  The only possible way I have come across is to subclass UIStoryboardSegue and put the initialisation in the init for the subclass.  Then I presume I call

```
UIStoryboardSegue * segue = [[SubclassedSegue alloc]initWithIdentifier:@"??what should this be??" source:self destination:targetViewContoller];
[segue perform];    // which just calls [super perform];
```

from the source view controller.  Is this correct?  Can anyone please show me some example code that uses this process - or preferably a simpler way that I haven't thought of?  I can't help thinking there must be an easier way to show a spinner.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segues should be subclassed only when you need to show custom animation/transition during the segue.

In usual scenario, you would want to do this:

```
__ block Destination *destinationVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"destination "];

    //START BUSY CURSOR HERE
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), 
    ^{
        // init whatever you want for destinationVC HERE.
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), 
      ^{
        //STOP BUSY CURSOR 
       //PERFORM UI UPDATE HERE
       [self presentViewController:destinationVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    });
```

Comment: +1: thats also a way :) I would keep the loading indicator on the destinationVC but this is what OP asked for (still don't think it is good :D)

Comment: yeah i was little surprised too why initing destVC from source.

Comment: Thank you - so we're just using presentViewController, and not using the segue at all?  [Note - I was originally doing the initialising on the destination VC, but until it's initialised (while the spinner is showing) it will just be a blank screen.  Also as I said there is code in shouldAutoRotate that will cause a crash if it is called before initialisation, which it will be if the view is shown too soon.]

Comment: You can use pushviewcontroller method of navigation controller as well.

Comment: OK, thanks Nirav.  The answer seems to be that I can't do this while using a segue from the storyboard - or at least not without messing with things that I shouldn't be messing with.  Just instantiate the VC, initialise, set a modalTransitionStyle and call presentViewController.

Comment: modalTransitionStyle & Push Segues should work as an alternative to presentViewController & pushviewcontroller - respectively. If you use segue, just use performseguewithidentifier, else use one of presentViewController or pushviewcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

just have the destinationViewController always add an activityIndicator and in viewWillAppear .. just hide it if you don't need it anymore

Alternatively pass a flag to the destinationViewController in prepareForSegue.

**You shouldn't need to subclass UISegue!**